# Unit Test Project References Console Application VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am aware that there are many questions already answered about this but nothing works for me.

I have a Console Application that I need to be unit tested. I have the Unit Test project in the same solution, both of them target the same platform, I added the reference from The Unit test project to the Console App and a few other things that I don't remember at the moment since I've been stuck for two days on this one. Yet, the Unit Tests don't recognize the namespace of the referenced project.

[image]

It says "The type or namespace name CLASSNAME does not exist in the namespace NAMESPACE", when it clearly does.

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue, since I've checked all the obvious ones and it still doesn't want to work?

Comment: Without code (declaration in production and access in test) it's hard to tell. Are you sure your production classes are not `internal`?

Comment: They are not internal. I have just once class that is Public Static besides the main class.

Comment: Can you post the unit test code with the line which shows the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that you want to initialize at the UnitTest project from the main project must be public. By default the c# classes are internal. So first check if the desired class that you want to unit test is a public class. Then add the needed using statement and everything should work.

Comment: It was private static, but I changed it to public static and nothing changed. It still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Did you add the right using statement? For example 
using MyNamespaceClass; at the top of your UnitTest file?